# How to store and get data from cache and only fetch the new/updated data from firestore (javascript sdk)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know how to store the data in the cache when the user come to my website first time and for the subsequent visit I want to fetch the data from cache and only want to fetch new data/updated data from the server.
Right now, it fetches data every time user comes to my website, which causes a lot of reads, so I want to reduce those reads by storing data in the cache.

My code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
// firebase import
import { collection, limit, onSnapshot, orderBy, query, where } from "firebase/firestore"

import { db } from "../firebase/config"

export const useCollection = (c) => {
  const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    let ref = collection(db, c)

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(ref, (snapshot) => {
      const results = []
      snapshot.docs.forEach(
        (doc) => {
          results.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error)
          setError("could not fetch the data")
        }
      )
      // update state
      setDocuments(results)
      setIsLoading(false)
      setError(null)
    })

    // unsubscribe to the previous listener before running the side effect again
    return () => unsubscribe()
  }, [openTab])

  return { documents, error, isLoading }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#web-version-9)?

Comment: I have checked that. I have one question If my website never goes offline, will it always fetch the data from firestore, not from the cache? One more thing Does the cache automatically gets deleted after some time?

Comment: No, it'll fetch data from local cache even if you are connected to internet AND there are no changes on the server. It'll always check for the server first and you'll be charged only for the changes fetched

Comment: Okay, got it. So, if the user creates/deletes/updates the document, it will update the cache accordingly? Is there any down side to this approach like this is how normally people do caching in firestore? or there are other ways to do caching as well?

Comment: One more thing Does the cache automatically gets deleted after some time?

Comment: Hi you can get information on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQOTjUko9WM)

Comment: Does this resolve your issue ?

Comment: It solves the issue, but there are some problems with the approach. First, users can't open more than two tabs, and second, offline persistence is supported only by the Chrome, Safari, and Firefox web browsers.

Comment: You can use [react-query](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/overview) and wrap all firestore calls within it if the default cache solution didn't work for you. As react-query caches every call done by it and the next request data will be retrieved from the cache.

Comment: Okay, thanks for sharing that. One question I have Does react-query persist the cache when we go from one page to another?

Comment: This question fall outside of this Stack Overflow's question I recommend you to ask raise another question